A sliding window overlapping the wall
I am planning a renovation that includes replacing the windows. The openings for the windows are 1-by-1 meters each. I was offered the following options:

Two sliding windows 1-by-0.5 each, such that each of them can be moved to overlap the other. But then I can only have 50% of the area open each time.
Pocket window: either one sliding window 1-by-1, or two sliding windows 1-by-0.5, that go into a pocket in the wall. This allows 100% opening, but the pocket in the wall reduces the thermal insulation of the wall, which is not good as the apartment is in a mountainy, cold region.
Axis window: either one axis window 1-by-1, or two axis windows 1-by-0.5, that open on an axis, either inwards or outwards. This allows 100% opening, but takes space inside the room or in the garden.

As all these options are not very good, I thought of a fourth option:

A sliding 1-by-1 window, or two 1-by-0.5 windows, that slide on a rail fixed in the wall, such that when they are opened, they overlap the wall adjacent to the window.

Apparently, this idea has none of the above disadvantages. But, when I asked my window expert, he said "there is no such thing". He did not explain why: is there a principal reason why such a window cannot work? Are there other disadvantages that I did not think of?
Alternatively, is there another solution that (1) allows 100% opening, (2) does not require digging into the wall, (3) does not take space inside or outside the house when it is opened?

What's your reason for wanting the entire opening to, well, open?  And what's the problem with windows opening into the garden?


A sliding 1-by-1 window, or two 1-by-0.5 windows, that slide on a rail fixed in the wall, such that when they are opened, they overlap the wall adjacent to the window.

I tend to agree with those who say that you would probably be more satisfied with either casement or standard sliding (vertical or horizontal) windows than you expect now.  However, if you really want what you described, consider adding an additional wall next to the existing wall.  Put one or two pocket windows in the additional wall.  The wall does not need to be much longer than the travel of the window, just long enough to cover the window opening and the pockets.
Advantages:

This is now a standard pocket window, not something new that no one has ever seen.
You're adding to the wall width, so you improve insulation rather than taking it away.
You can open the window fully.
The window travels normally within wall space.

Disadvantages:

You have to build the extra wall.
The wall reduces the space in your room.  However, as already noted, your idea does as well.  This just ensures that you won't block the area where the window needs to open.

Incidentally, with similar thoughts, I went with the casement windows opening out and have been generally satisfied.

Your fourth option is essentially a pocket window that is placed just outside the wall (either on the inside or the outside of the house). The problem with that option is that there is nothing to fix the window frame to and no way to make it all watertight and draft free.
The problem with your request for alternative solutions is that the glass in the window opening needs to go somewhere when you open the window. And you essentially rule out all the normal places where the glass could go to. The only option you didn't rule out is to remove the window pane completely and place it somewhere out of the way. But your window expert will quickly veto that one, based on how heavy those glass panes are and the likelihood that you will break one in the foreseeable future.
As there is no solution that fits all your criteria, the best advise we can give is to think hard about your priorities and go with the least bad option.

They don't exist for a few reasons I can think of:

The need is fairly rare. Most folks are fine with the other options, and if you have wall space for the pane to lap, why not just install a larger window of a simpler type?

The motion required is rather complex. To clear even a few inches of jamb depth you need a robust articulating mechanism.

Practically speaking, you wouldn't be able to have furniture in the operating zone. You'd need an adequate gap for clearance and handling.

Operation would be cumbersome. Most people can barely handle a typical window without verging on frustration. This would be unpopular simply for the attention it would require to manipulate.

Sealing would be more challenging. You'd need some sort of clamp at both sides, rather than the single-sided latch a casement gets by with.

Jamb depths vary enough that either several motion options or a range of adjustability would be needed to make it marketable.

Casement windows (what I think you're calling "axis" windows) are fine for most people. The 20-30cm of depth needed for good airflow usually isn't a concern outside.

Due to the lack of scale economy, and due to the need for extra hardware and probably tempered glass, cost would be much higher than a conventional window.


